# How to translate "Industry expertise" to Russian?

Tags: перевод, английский

having difficulty with translating "Industry expertise" to Russian.
appreciate all input!
thanks.

Comment: "промышленная оценка", if I understand the term correctly.

Comment: Is it about a person or about a product?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think *industry* in this context refers to *производство*. In English, term *industry expertise* usually refers to specialist knowledge in any particular area, which could be finance, computing, etc.  Therefore, in relation to a person, I would translate phrase

> He has industry expertise

as

> Он - компетентный специалист

Comment: The term seems remarkably similar to 'subject matter expertise'.

I would translate it as:
    Знание предметной области

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the context.
If applied to person like:

```
He has industry expertise.
```

that could be translated as

```
Он имеет производственный опыт.
```

or

```
Он компетентный в вопросах производства.
```

or

```
Он разбирается в производстве.
```

or

```
Он знаком с производством.
```

Answer (score 0):

What we hear more and more often in these days is the calque from English, 'экспертиза'. However, this new usage of the word is largely limited to international businesses and hasn't yet made way to the wide audience.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wiling to show high level of expertise of some person, you could use quite common phrase "признанный эксперт". But that is having slight accent on accepting his expertise by others.

> Сергей Михайлович был признанным экспертом в области машиностроительства.

Or, you could emphasise his high-level expertise alone with "высококлассный специалист", "профессионал высокого класса":

> Сергей Михайлович был высококлассным специалистом по древообрабатывающим станкам

Comment: "emphasise" I'm sure

Answer (score 0):

- Отраслевая экспертиза
- Промышленная экспертиза
- Промышленная оценка
- Экспертная промышленная оценка
- Экспертиза промышленности

and many other variants, depending on context

Comment: Industry expertise может быть и строчкой в резюме.